# Rails - Do I need to define 'new' action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `routes.rb` I have the line `resources :items`.  I have a `new.html.erb` file that is using `form_for @item do ...` to build a form.  In my items controller I define the new action:

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
end
```

I am wondering what is the point of this new action definition.  When the form is submitted I have a create action that handles it.  Is it only for using form_for?  What happens if I leave it out?  Is there any rails magic going on that will assume this is what I want?

Comment: Nothing will assume that's what you want. The Rails form helper requires an item. Finding out what happens when you leave it out seems easy enough.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well I meant similar to how you don't need to define index.

Comment: Which version of Rails?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm using rails 4.  I don't have index defined in my controller but I can still navigate to /items and it will display what I have in my index.html.erb file.  Granted I am not trying to access an instance variable in the view so I guess it's a little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new` creates a new object for the form_for.  The form_for will know to submit `create` (instead of `update`) because the object is not persisted.  And 'form_for' needs an object anyway (as do all model-backed forms).

`new` also gives you an opportunity to set up initial values for some attributes, if you so desire.

So, all in all, it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the *new* action will handle **only** GET requests. The *create* action will handle **only** *POST* requests. You can take a look of how Rails respond to specific request methods, using the `rake routes` command.

The *new* action will respond to the browser's GET html request and assign a empty object, because the user didn't input anything yet. No validation error will be shown.

The *create* action expects the user has already submitted the form, and will trigger validations/etc. Then, if something wrong happened, it will re-render the form with validation errors. Otherwise, by default a `redirect_to` will be triggered.

This is just the default. Rails is a Opinionated Framework, but very very flexible.